# Android p2p GPS app

Tags: android, wifi, p2p

I am looking to implement a cloud application that allows one to save contacts and if the contact also has the app on, see on a map where the contact is (if in close proximity to you).

I've been looking around towards how to do so and the first step is to establish a connection.

For my purposes, a centralized server to which apps connect and fetch repeatedly updated database information about other users is unsatisfactory as this is too "centralized" for a cloud app.

I've some experience with Bluetooth but in my opinion and experience, bluetooth is not practical as the two devices must then be in very very close proximity with each other.

Thus my question is this, how do android phones connect p2p without the use of local wifi? If that is even possible?

Thank you for your time

Comment: look on this May it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288820/application-direct-file-sharing-over-wifi-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thus my question is this, how do android phones connect p2p without the use of local wifi? If that is even possible?

Yes, via Bluetooth where available, but it will probably not meet your needs. So, in practice, the answer to your question is no. You will need the local wifi.

That being said, you could attempt multicast on the LAN to detect other connected devices enabled with your application. If you want more than LAN, you will need a fully fledge solution including super peers and a P2P framework, like JXTA